# replacement and two for loop in R

Tags: r

I would like to have a vector `res`  with length 200, which includes 20 times repetition of random generation values divided by 2 which is `r[i]`, how can I get this in R?I wrote the following code but it is just save each iteration values,not the whole iterations.

```
r = rep(0, 10)
res = matrix(0, nrow=200, ncol=1)
for(j in 1:20){
  for(i in 1:10){
    x = rnorm(10, 0, 1)
    r[i] = x/2
  }
  res = rbind(r)
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `matrix(norm(200, 0, 1)/2, ncol=10)`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but I want to solve it with two loop, how can i do it ?

Comment: Do you have to use 2 `for` loops for your assignment?

Comment: @Roland the question the OP asks is valid, so the remark you made is not really constructive. No insult intended, but if you do not want to answer the question, do not answer the question. In addition, it includes more of a reproducible example than many, many other questions in the `R` tag.

Answer (score 2):

as Roland said in a comment to your question writing two loops for this isn't a good practice. However, you can do it like this

```
res = rep(0, 200)
r = rep(0, 10)
for(j in 1:20){
    for(i in 1:10){
        x = rnorm(1, 0, 1)
        r[i] = x/2
    }
    res[((j-1)*10+1):(j*10)] = r
}
```

As for your solution, there were some problems:

1. There is no need to define a matrix `res = matrix(0, nrow=200, ncol=1)` if you only need a vector
2. `rnorm(10,0,1)` returns a vector of 10 values so assigning it to `r[i]` (which takes only one value) isn't correct
3. `rbind` is used to connect two vectors/matrices/... by rows so using it with only one parameter doesn't really make a sense here

Comment: +1, although adding what the OP was doing wrong (and why this works) would make the answer even better.